# Jinja in Python: How to make IF statements work?

Tags: python, latex, jinja2

I am trying to automate some document generation with Jinja in a Python environment.
I customised the jinja environment in order not to get conflicts with default character meanings in my IDE. The line_statement_prefix is set to #.

```
    latex_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    block_start_string = '\BLOCK{',
    block_end_string = '}',
    variable_start_string = '\VAR{',
    variable_end_string = '}',
    comment_start_string = '%',
    comment_end_string = '}',
    line_statement_prefix = '#',
    line_comment_prefix = '%#',
    trim_blocks = True,
    autoescape = False,
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.abspath('.')))
```

I am trying to conditionally activate rows of a table, if a particular cell content is not 'nan'.

```
{# if \VAR{row['Climate (where PUE is located)']} not 'nan'}
{{Climate & \VAR{row['Climate (where PUE is located)']}\\}}
{# endif}
```

So far, any possible variation of the if statement did not yield the desired outcome.
I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to check for a string with letters n, a, n or for a float which is a NaN?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the content of \VAR cannot be accessed for evaluation, it is just possible to "print" it statically to the document that's being generated.

I solved the issue by generating a .tex document containing all vallues (including nan), then let a little script run over said .tex file in order to remove all rows with nan-value.